# MySQL Union always returns one row with NULL's

Tags: mysql, null, union

Given the following query…

```
  SELECT   DISTINCT *
  FROM     PAS_Post
  WHERE    post_user_id = 21
  GROUP BY post_post_id 

UNION

  SELECT   DISTINCT PAS_Post.*
  FROM     PAS_Follow LEFT JOIN PAS_Post ON (
             PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id = PAS_Post.post_user_id
           )
  WHERE    PAS_Follow.folw_follower_user_id = 21
  GROUP BY post_post_id

ORDER BY post_posted_date DESC
```

I always get a row in the results that is just NULL's, unfortunately I need to preserve some NULL values in the data as the Post's table (PAS_Post) holds different types of information.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction to get rid of this null row.

[image]

I do not want or need the last row here

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output

Comment: Don't use an outer join in the second part of the `UNION`: i.e. change `LEFT JOIN` for `INNER JOIN` (or just `JOIN`, which is the same thing).

Comment: Put that in an answer and I shall up vote you as that worked beautifully, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a (left) outer join in the second part of the `UNION`, so any cases that do not satisfy the join criteria will result in data from the table on the left of the join (`PAS_Follow`), but `NULL` in every column of the table on the right of the join (`PAS_Post`); the subsequent selection only of columns from the latter table results in the `NULL` rows that you observe.  Therefore, the simplest solution is to use an inner join (that completely excludes records where the join criteria is not met).

However, in your case, it appears that your query can be greatly simplified by simply using two possible conditions in a filter on the joined tables rather than a `UNION`:

```
SELECT   p.*
FROM     PAS_Post   AS p
    JOIN PAS_Follow AS f ON f.folw_followed_user_id = p.post_user_id
WHERE    p.post_user_id = 21
      OR f.folw_follower_user_id = 21
ORDER BY p.post_posted_date DESC
```

I have excluded the `GROUP BY` clause on the assumption that `post_post_id` is the primary key (or at very least is `UNIQUE`) in your `PAS_Post` table.  If that assumption is incorrect, you may want to reintroduce it—but beware that MySQL will indeterminately select the values that will be returned from each group.